# Change background color after X seconds when typing in an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, keypress

I have a `contenteditable` div and when you type in it, after 2 seconds I try to change its background color.

This is my code:

```
function changeFn(){
      $(this).css('background','red')
      console.log($(this).attr('id'));
   } 
var timer;

    $("div.content").on("keypress paste", function () { 

        clearTimeout(timer);
          timer = setTimeout(changeFn, 2000)
    });
```

It seems that I have to pass $(this) to the function because it doesn't recognize which $this is.

When I set the background-color change inside the keypress function it works.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uc8Tg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy), which sets the context of a function:

```
function changeFn() {
    $(this).css('background', 'red');
}
var timer;

$("div.content").on("keypress paste", function() {

    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout($.proxy(changeFn, this), 2000);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uc8Tg/1/

Comment: Thank you very much. Once again Ive learned something new from you.

Comment: @jQuerybeast: Glad to help, as always!

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeFn(){
    $(this).css('background','red')
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
} 
var timer;
$("div.content").on("keypress paste", function () { 
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var self = this;
    timer = setTimeout(function(){changeFn.call(self)}, 2000)
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Thank you. I will be using Andrew's answer as it uses less coding

Comment: I mean slower in the technical sense of the word, not that you can really notice: "Call" is a native javascript method for every function; check how inside jQuery he is just doing a lot of things and then, at the end it uses "apply" (wich is just like "call" but that accepts an array to create the arguments) http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.7/jQuery.proxy